# How do I go about converting .docx into an array or dictionary?

Tags: ios, data-structures, converters, docx

I am currently trying to build an iOS game that match word with its definition for myself and my classmates.

I'm having a hard time thinking how do I go about converting a list of words with their definitions in a .docx files into something(JSON, XML, ...) that I can then read it into an Array or Dictionary.

Most of the words in the .docx have the following format:
" Word (): Definition. "

Comment: Does Max Langerak answers suit to you ? Do you really want to convert docx to an array or can you tell your users to save as JSON or XML ?

Comment: @edi9999 All I wanted is an easy way to convert a .docx that is on my computer into a JSON or XML files, so i can copy it to my project. Max Langerak's answer does suit with what I'm trying to do. (too bad i can't vote up yet with my current reputation point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be easier with excel. Excel already has the function to export to xml, and should make your life a lot easier, instead of getting all the words out of docx and then converting them to either JSON or XML.

http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/xml.html